# sending mail with java sendmail in GWT servlet deployed to tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, email, tomcat, gwt

I have an eclipse project compiled in java 1.7 and delpoyed to tomcat 6. When I use the code below to send an email I get the following error:

```
at com.google.appengine.api.mail.stdimpl.GMTransport.sendMessage(GMTransport.java:236)
at javax.

maicom.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'mail' or call 'Send()' was not found.
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:109)
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:64)
    at com.google.appengine.api.mail.MailServiceImpl.doSend(MailServiceImpl.java:101)
    at com.google.appengine.api.mail.MailServiceImpl.send(MailServiceImpl.java:34)
l.Transport.send(Transport.java:95)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:48)
...
```

the code is:

```
  try {

      Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from, "hello from admin"));
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
    new InternetAddress(to, “user”));
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setText(message);


      Transport.send(msg);


  } catch (AddressException e) {
    myPrint("Address exception: "+e);

      // ...
  } catch (MessagingException e) {
    myPrint("Messaging exception: "+e);

      // ...
  }
```

I have placed the latest oracle mail.jar and associated lib folder into the war/WEB-INF/lib directory before creating and deploying the war file.

Although there are one or two similar reports on stack overflow none seem to provide a solution to this issue.

Comment: Why do you use an App Engine package if you deploy it to your own server?

Comment: Andrei : to what specific package are your referring? Or are you suggesting that there is something wrong in the project settings/configuration?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

**Cause**: Google app engine had been added to the project at an earlier stage. Google app engine classes shadow javax.mail classes so that imports of javax.mail classes in the source do not show up as unresolved references in the IDE. Therefore, I was compiling with the app engine versions unwittingly. Deploying app engine code to own server results in this error because the wrong class library is being referenced.

**Solution**:

1. Rebuild the project without adding the GWT app engine functionality.
2. Create a library folder, import the java mail .jar files you need
   and add to build path: For Eclipse IDE: right click on the files and
   select Add to build path.
3. Recompile and deploy to own server. The code (as above) will then
   work.